# SFTP failing with "Match Group" clause

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ftp, sftp

I am attempting to set up an sftp server on ubuntu/precise on EC2. I have been successful in adding a new user that can connect via ssh, however once I add the following clause:

```
Match Group sftp
    ChrootDirectory /home/%u
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I can no longer connect (at all, ssh or otherwise) and I get the message

```
Error: Connection refused
Error: Could not connect to server
```

I am able to connect with the subsystem set to:

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

Any idea why the ssh server is failing with this "Match" clause? Essentially, everything is working except for the "chroot" part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, solved the issue:

2 things were causing a problem

1. I had to move the "Match" Clause to the END of the file, it was in the middle
2. There was a permissions issue - found the answer elsewhere that fixed it

from: https://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes

"All this pain is thanks to several security issues as detailed here. Basically the chroot directory has to be owned by root and can't be any group-write access. Lovely. So you essentially need to turn your chroot into a holding cell and within that you can have your editable content.

```
sudo chown root /home/bob
sudo chmod go-w /home/bob
sudo mkdir /home/bob/writable
sudo chown bob:sftponly /home/bob/writable
sudo chmod ug+rwX /home/bob/writable
```

And bam, you can log in and write in /writable."

Comment: Pffff, I've been messing around with this for a whole day now, and this was my problem, too. "Match" directive has to be at the end!! Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me. It took a number of passes at trying to understand this before I finally got it done and this helped - thanks. What I still don't get is why the VSFTP server doesn't allow a log in if the directories aren't structured correctly. If it allowed you to sign it and then just not show you anything it would be more suggestive that there was a file permission issue

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that /home and /home/%u are chowned to root:root.